# "No display manager selected for the display manager module" while installating Debian

Tags: debian, system-installation, debian-installer

I was trying to install debian 10.5.0 to my laptop with live CD (downloaded from [debian official website](https://cdimage.debian.org/mirror/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/10.5.0-live+nonfree/amd64/iso-hybrid/)), the installation failed on about 48% and error message as below

> **Installation Failed**
>
> No display managers selected for the displaymanager module.
>
> The list is empty after checking for installed display managers.

[image]

Any idea how to fix that? Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I got that error while I was installing with gnome dm. I just switched to xfce iso and that error did not occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can reproduce. Every Debian-Gnome package (nonfree + live/nonfree) has that problem. Debian KDE or LXDE version installs without any problem. [image]

So, I installed amd46 nonfree live Debian 10.04 from the archive and upgraded manually.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will follow your method. Thanks